# How to unit and/or integration test parsers?

Tags: parsing, testing, architecture

I am wondering what the general principles are for testing that a parser properly parses into an AST. I have tried in the past to test the structure of the AST, but there are two huge problems with this.

1. **Readability**. It's hard to read the test and understand what it's doing.
2. **Maintainability**. There are a huge number of tests to write, so compounds readability. And if you change the parser at all, you might need to rewrite all of your tests.

Say our parser is in JavaScript and our AST is in JSON. Instead of testing the JSON AST output structure matches some "expected" JSON object, like this:

```
assert.deepEqual(parse('x = 10'), {
  type: 'assignment',
  left: {
    type: 'variable',
    name: 'x',
  },
  right: {
    type: 'integer',
    value: 10
  }
})
```

I would instead do something like this:

```
test('x = 10')

function test(str) {
  let parsed = parse(str)
  let generated = stringify(parsed)
  assert.equal(str, generated)
}
```

Then it would be going full-circle, from string back to string, and you would only have to read the input string. What are the pros and cons of this, and is there a better standard approach? One con with this is that your stringifier has to *format* the string exactly the same way as the initially written string, which might be less than ideal. But one major pro with this is that you can simply write out your string once, and it is easy to read your tests. You just make sure your `test` function isn't cheating and returning the initial string, obviously :).

Note: The example I wrote of `x = 10` is an extremely simple example. To robustly test the parser we are going to need complex full programs with all the features integrated, so the AST will become even more of a nightmare to "mentally parse" to figure out what the test does, if you compare ASTs to expected JSON structures.

Also note: This is just testing the AST generator works. A separate *compiler* will also have to eventually be tested. But here we don't concern ourselves with the compiler, and instead are only focused on the parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your first solution is "better" than your second idea.

However, don't check for exact equality.  Do "contains" type tests.  The result AST should contain "type: variable; name: x".  That's one test. And it should contain "type: integer; value: 10".  And it should contain "left { variable }".  A third test.  Now, all 3 tests could be parts of one test and there could be more parts.  But think of what semantics you want to capture and make certain they are captured.

Moreover, turn those checks into assertions--not just in your test, but in your AST builder.  The AST builder should assert that the lhs of an assignment AST is something assignable (initially just a variable, but more things as you loosen it).

You can do that with strings too, but it is actually harder unless you have control over your strings or you write a custom diff that checks them.  Moreover, you don't really know in terms of semantics whether the string test has proven anything.  You know you got the same string back, but that can be because you have corresponding flaws in how you read and write something.  And that is a mistake you are actually likely to make.

Finally, in my last project we used json outputs for many things, and I wrote a json diff checker.  So, that we could save the json once a test "worked" and then compare the json output for all subsequent runs.  Yes, that is a "change detector" but when writing compilers, you really want to know when you have changed how something is parsed and not have it be an accident.  You don't inspect the json output by hand, unless it has changed (and then if you are ok with the change) you simply save that file as the new regression check.  And, if there are parts of json, you expect to vary, simply make your diff tool ignore those differences (perhaps just logging them).  See my comparison examples, to see what kinds of things you might want to "match" in your diff tool.

Answer (score 1):

> One con with this is that your stringifier has to format the string exactly the same way as the initially written string, which might be less than ideal.

You should not run into this problem, in the sense if you do, JSON should in this scenario be stable one re-encoding.

That is if the AST is JSON text and the equality assertion is again JSON text, both JSON text can be decoded and then you can do your assertion:

```
actualJsonText = parse('x = 10');
expectedJsonText = lastAssertedSuccess();

assert.deepEqual(decode(actualJsonText), decode(expectedJsonText))
lastAsserted(actualJsonText);
```

Similar with varying scenarios, e.g. parse() actually has the AST:

```
actualJsonText = encode(parse('x = 10'));
expectedJsonText = lastAssertedSuccess();

assert.deepEqual(decode(actualJsonText), decode(expectedJsonText))
lastAsserted(actualJsonText);
```

these may not be the best unit tests as it creates a database that will grow over time. however it allows you to test output for input and if the JSON text is in a pretty-print format, a standard text differ will show what changed in a human readable format.

in case a test is a false positive, the new good master can be used to easily overwrite the last known good assertion. that is, you can relatively easily maintain this kind of test-suite.

I often create such known input -> expected output test-suites when I write a parser or similar (e.g. a tokenizer: binary string -> token stream) and I want to put the overall functionality under test and have a database of known goods to capture regressions.

For that it works pretty well and efficient. It requires when an assertion fails to understand the reason - the test is not telling you that.

What these kind of tests also don't tell you are the internals (of a parser state for example) and you may want more dedicated tests upfront, but these highly depend on the implementation details. And the implementation can be done test-driven, so this is already covered then.